# Can't reuse style in silverlight 5

Tags: silverlight, styles, visualstatemanager, visualstates

I create a custom image button and add some style. everything works fine. But when i try to reuse it in other buttons, it didn't work very well. only 1 button will follow the style, others are always blank.

i didn't got any error in runtime. Please help!!

Thx

Here are the code:

Button:

```
    public class ImageTextButton : Button
{
    public DependencyProperty TextProperty { get; set; }
    public DependencyProperty ImageProperty { get; set; }

    public ImageTextButton()
    {
        TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(ImageTextButton), null);
        ImageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ImageSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ImageTextButton), null);
    }

    public ImageSource ImageSource
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageProperty, value); }
    }

    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

xaml:

```
<Controls:ImageTextButton HorizontalAlignment="Left" Command="{Binding SendCustomerChanges}" Style="{StaticResource ImageTextButton}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=DetailsInformation.IsAllowSave}"
                             Text="{Binding Path=CustomerResources.Button_CloseDetailedView, Source={StaticResource ResourceWrapper}}" ImageSource="{Binding Path=SaveIcon, Source={StaticResource ApplicationIcons}}" />
```

style:

```
    <Style TargetType="Controls:ImageTextButton" x:Key="ImageTextButton" >
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Controls:ImageTextButton">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommomStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="LightGray" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" >
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#AAAAAA" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Fill="#E0E9F1"  StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#728DA3"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" Fill="#F5F5F5" IsHitTestVisible="false" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#D3D3D3" Opacity="0" />
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Grid.Column="0" Width="12" Height="12" Margin="2,0,2,0" Source="{TemplateBinding ImageSource}">
                        </Image>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" x:Name="textBlock" Margin="2,3,4,0" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" />
                    </Grid>
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,3,5,3"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things you need to change/fix.

1. Your Text Depenency Property is badly formed. You must define a getter and setter for the DP (as you have done with the ImageSourceProperty).
2. Your ImageSource Dependency Property needs some attention too... The DP should be named ImageSourceProperty ... `Dependency Properties must follow the pattern` **[described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms752914.aspx)** `if they are to work under all conditions. Especially so when you are setting them from XAML`
3. You need a `default style key` for your new class so that your style is actually applied
4. Your dependency properties should be registered in a static constructor (or as a field initializer. Not in the instance constructor.

   ```
   public class ImageTextButton : Button
   {
       public ImageTextButton()
       {
           DefaultStyleKey = typeof(ImageTextButton);
       }

       static ImageTextButton()
       {
           TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(ImageTextButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));
           ImageSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ImageSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ImageTextButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));
       }

       public string Text
       {
           get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
           set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
       }

       // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Text.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
       public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty;



       public ImageSource ImageSource
       {
           get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }
           set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
       }

       // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ImageSource.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
       public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty;


   }
   ```